# How to tell if Caching is working. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following along with the 'Agile Web Development with Rails 4' guide and have come to a section on caching. Here are the steps to follow:

1. in config/environments/development.rb

   ```
   config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
   ```
2. In app/models/product.rb

   ```
   def self.latest
       Product.order(:updated_at).last
   end
   ```
3. in views/store/index.html.erb

   ```
   <% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
       <% @products.each do |product| %>
           <% cache ['entry', product] do %>
               <div class="entry">
                   <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
                   <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
                   <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
                   <div class="price_line">
                       <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
                   </div>
              </div>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   ```

To verify the cash is working, the book says: "As far as verifying that this works, unfortunately there isn't much to see. If you go to that page, you should see nothing change, which in fact is the point! The best you can do is to make a change to the template anywhere inside the cache block without updating any product and verifying that you do not see that update because the cached version of the page has not been updated".

However, when I try and add a "Hello" string in the code within the cache blocks, it appears on the page. I've done all the server restarting and what not.

But, when I reload the page on my local host I do see this line

```
    Cache digest for app/views/store/index.html.erb: 6c620ede1d4e824439a7b0e3b177620f
```

which is not their when I have 
        config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

Link to git hub repo: https://github.com/BrianLobdell/depot

Thank you,
Brian

Comment: so what? everything seems to work...

Comment: The way to test in the book said to add something into the cache block that didn't modify a product (like the "hello" string) and if the cache was working it would not show up on the page. However, in my case, the "Hello" string did show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails updates the cache when changing the file, so it's easier to manipulate the cache instead.

You can retrieve the cache fragment using the cache digest for the page in your Rails console (the digest might have changed, make sure to use the recent one!):

```
key = ['store', Product.latest, '6c620ede1d4e824439a7b0e3b177620f']
ActionController::Base.new.read_fragment(key)
```

This should return the cached fragment. To ensure that Ruby actually hits the cache when serving the page, you could replace the fragment with some other content:

```
ActionController::Base.new.write_fragment(key, 'it works!')
```

Reload the page, you should see *"it works!"*.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this so I am a little confused as to where this code should go and what exactly it does.

Comment: I'm also confused as to why the code given in the example from the book couldn't be tested in the way the book describes.

Comment: You run the code from the [Rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console): type `rails console` in your terminal to launch it.

Comment: What this code does: in your view `<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>` stores the blocks' rendered content in a fragment cache. `write_fragment` replaces this content with `"it works!"`. That's more or less what the authors suggest: change the cache block and reload the page.

Comment: Thank you! It displayed it works, but now every time I run development with cache it displays 'it works'. should I just do the same thing again with the new cache digest?

Comment: Just delete your app's `tmp/cache` directory.